# VirtualBox VM (Ubuntu 20.04) stays black after booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I just resized my Ubuntu VM Disk space cause it was running low on it. I did it in the VirtualBox GUI but after resizing I couldn´t fully boot ubuntu anymore. A blackscreen stays after the loading icon and ubuntu title on the bottom of the screen. I cant revert the resizing. Any solutions for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the VM - even a somewhat older backup?

Comment: As silly as it may sound: no, unfortunately not

Comment: You probably now need to build a new VM and make sure it is large enough for future. The way it sounds, I do not know another way,

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if there wasn't a single file that I kinda need. Is there any way to recover files from the virtual disk image?

Comment: See whether this Oracle article helps you.  .....  https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vdidetails.html

Answer (score 1):

For everybody else that gets the same error: The GUI of VirtualBox only extends the partition in the host system. If your Disk space is dynamically allocated then you still need to extend the main partition of your vm. For ubuntu you can do this with GParted. There are lots of useful explanations for this!

Damn, I got my files back..